Is it possible to make a wallet/multisig wallet that allows for execution of preset transactions?
My goal is to make a multisig such that there is hierarchical ownership where a wallet can perform transactions such as providing liquidity only to a particular pool using whitelisted assets but requires a second a third signer to approve any other transactions such as transferring of assets to another wallet?
Tl:dr i want the ability to be able to make a set of txs (i.e prewhitelisted transactions) but any txs outside the prewhitelisted txs to prewhitelisted contracts would need a second or third signer.

Yes you can set up a safe with a custom module enabled so that all transactions that respect some conditions are sent to the module, which will automatically validate them, while all the other transactions will be sent directly to the safe, where a n/m threshold will apply.
Please let me know if that answered your question! Best, Louis
